# Setting Text to an Editable DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to remove the text in the div element when clicked if the text is "Text".

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<body>
     <div class="txtField" onclick="emptyField()">
          <p>Text</p>
     </div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function emptyField() {
    var textVar = document.getElementById("txtField");
    if (textVar.textContent === "Text")
    {
        textVar.textContent = "";
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: :3 Hi Charlietfl this is why I'm checking what is in the field upon click time...
You know how this box has ghostly text like "Write a message here..." Well I didn't want that text to actually exist and be editable to the user. So whilst this message exist, it deletes upon click. ^^

Comment: Yeah I must have been looking at it wrong. Makes sense if only removing default

Comment: It's alright Charlie! I could've explained it in my problem description. Would you like me to clarify it in the problem? :))

Comment: No it's fine this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier just to pass a reference to the element, and when you're comparing strings against element text, make sure to `trim()` it first.

```js
function emptyField(el) {
  if (el.textContent.trim() === "Text") el.textContent = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="txtField" onclick="emptyField(this)" contenteditable="true">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have lots of syntax errors my friend :) As listed below:

```
var textV = document.getElementById("txtField"); // issue here
```

You have named `textV` while you are using `textVar`. Also you are using `document.getElementById("txtField")` while you have no **id** attribute in your **div**, you have **class** instead in your HTML.

```
 <div class="txtField" onclick="emptyField()" contenteditable="true">
```

So, fix these errors first.

```
function emptyField() {
    var textV = document.getElementById("txtField"); // Issue here 
    if (textVar.textContent === "Text") // using textVar
    {
        textVar.textContent = "";
    }
}
```

THEN USE THIS CODE AND THIS WILL WORK AS EXPECTED:

```js
const div = document.querySelector(".txtField");

div.addEventListener("click",emptyField);
function emptyField() {
    var textV = document.querySelector(".txtField p");
    if (textV.innerText === "Text")
    {
        textV.innerText = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<body>
     <div class="txtField"  contenteditable="true">
          <p>Text</p>
     </div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And no it is not because you have your div as **contenteditable**

Comment: The `<p>` may not exist which will throw error trying to access it's properties

Comment: <33 Thank you, you are an ANGEL!! <33 What a friendly answer. :))
I'd accept it as THE answer but Kinglish's answer was very precise.
But, your answer taught me so much as someone new to scripting Javascript.
:D

Comment: @RainbowDoritosAreMine I am glad I was able to help in one way or the other. My intentions are actually to help fellow coders from whatever little I know. Accepting or not accepting an answer hardly matters my Friend.
Lots of Respect. And I am a simple person dear. Angels are sinless, we as human are prone to error and often commit mistakes :) 

Since you said you are new to scripting language. Any time you need help just ping me. Also, NetNinja is an online youtube channel from where I have learned a lot. You can learn so much from there. 
CHEERS !!! Bye Take care